# iOS app crashes when set UITextfield delegates

Tags: ios, uitextfield, exc-bad-access

I dont know why the iPhone app crashes and it gives lldb error only.I tried to add the exception break point too.

.h file:

```
 IBOutlet UITextField *etCountry;
```

.m file:

```
etCountry.delegate=self;///
```

This is the line i am getting the crash.Please give me the solution for me

[image]

Comment: Post your crash report..

Comment: @MKR i posted my screens about the app crash

Comment: i think your iboutlet connection broken,have you check your nib file's owners?

Comment: @Kalai show your log navigator

Comment: @MKR i got only lldb in log navigator

Comment: try to remove the connect of the textfield and then add it again.

Comment: @Kalai then just check for connections attribute, may be a IBOutlet connection issue

Comment: @Kalai ungaloda console error report post panunga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your textfield has connection like this below images,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how

```
 self.etCountry.delegate=self;
```

And add

```
 @interface YourViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
 @end
```

Comment: `self` refer for only have the property for `UIElements` .

Comment: I really did that.But still i got this error message

Comment: What? Could you please show me more code on that ViewController?

Comment: Then, The problem should be in the storyBoard, check your IBOutlet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You may **check other threads**, and their stack. My guess is that there is everything is fine with text field. Seemingly there seems a network call also in the background, maybe a callback block is not in the right format. That caused similar "hidden" crashes to me.

[image]